# Navbar clickable not working in EJS template

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, ejs

I am new to node js and EJS template in it.I have a navbar in my navbar.ejs file with a drop-down toggle button in it.My problem is that the button does not work when clicked.Is this due to the EJS template or my code has gone wrong somewhere.Will script tag work inside ejs template file? Please help me out.

Assume that I have done the routing correctly and included all the files in the app.ejs file.

Thanks in advance :)

navbar.ejs

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" style="width:100%;overflow:hidden;height:30px;background-color:#595959;font-size:17px;font-family:'Segoe UI',Arial,sans-serif">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="margin-left:-20px">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <button type="" class="dropbtn" onclick="myfunction()" >ALL <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i> </button>
                <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 3</a>

                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

    <script>
        /* When the user clicks on the button, 
        toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
        function myfunction() {
            document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
        }

        // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
        window.onclick = function (e) {
            if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
                var myDropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
                if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                    myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

style.css

```
    .dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.dropdown .dropbtn {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: #595959;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

nav.navbar li.dropdown:hover div.dropdown-content {
            display: block;
        }
```

Comment: Have u link bootstrap css and js in your file

Comment: In what sense does it 'not work'? Is the class being added to the relevant element? Add some console logging in `myfunction` to see whether it gets called.

Comment: yes i have linked all the necessary files in the head tag

Answer (score 0):

try with importing following before `</body>` tag

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The navigation links are not working because currently their hrefs are dead links. Each links needs to have its href equal to the route it points to in the .js file. For example, in a normal situation, the home route always links to the '/' path, so if this is supposed to link to the home route, Link 1, then it becomes Link 1(or Home route) as I think it should. The same would apply for other routes. If link 2 was to link to a certain about route, then it should be Link 2( or about). I hope that makes sense.